# Docker PostgreSQL 12.3 how to debug failed transaction\ incomplete message

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, transactions, psql

Im using PostgreSQL 12.3 docker image, and i have an application that stopped working as some query transaction gets closed or incomplete in the middle of it and the application just doesn't work.

My question is, how can i see or make PostgreSQL to save the incomplete transaction ?
I want to see from where, when and what was the query and issue, is there any way to debug it?
or save it maybe on a error table ?

my psql log:

```
LOG:  incomplete message from client
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your application connects to the database with `psql`?

Comment: What do you see in the server's log file?  It should offer more lines of context than just that.

Comment: I have talked to postgres community and they said there is no way to get the missing transection, i ended up recreating the psql docker container with clean db and then copied all the db using python script that copy the missing data to the client container and it created the new data in db and now it works fine, it might was db corruption